# How to extract unique values from a data frame column?

Tags: r, function, unique, unique-values

I've been trying to create a function that extracts the unique values of a given column in a given data frame, by writing this code:

```
val_uniques <- function(colname, datframe)
  if colname %in% colnames(dataframe) {
    print(unique(dataframe[, colname], incomparables = FALSE))
  } else {
    print("cette colonne n'existe pas")
  }
```

but unfortunately, I keep getting this error :

> print( unique(dataframe[,colname] , incomparables = FALSE))} else { print("cette colonne n'existe pas")}
>   Error: unexpected '}' in "print( unique(dataframe[,colname] , incomparables = FALSE))}"

I know it's a dumb question because it has something to do with `}` in `if` or `else`, but I've tried everything and it didn't work.

P.S. It's my first programming stuff in R.

Comment: It should be `if (colname %in% colnames(dataframe)) { ...` - you are missing the brackets after `if`. Also check the spelling of your second argument: `datframe`. It should be `dataframe` I guess.

Comment: Thanks , i've done this , but i keep getting this error : Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: My new code looks like this :

Comment: val_uniques <- function (colname,dataframe)
 if (colname %in% colnames(dataframe)){
 print( unique(dataframe[,colname] , incomparables = FALSE)) 
 }
else  {print("cette colonne n'existe pas")
}

Comment: You have both `datframe` and `dataframe`. Correct that and it works. Oh, use open `{` and close `}` to start and end the function, it's more readable.

Comment: You are missing the `{` bracktes after `function (colname,dataframe)`. Try `val_uniques <- function (colname,dataframe) {if (colname %in% colnames(dataframe)){ print( unique(dataframe[,colname] , incomparables = FALSE)) } else {print("cette colonne n'existe pas") }}`

Comment: Thanks very much , it worked now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some typos in object names `datframe` and `dataframe` as well as curly brackets are misplaced:

```
val_uniques <- function(colname, dataframe) {
  if (colname %in% colnames(dataframe)) {
    print(unique(dataframe[, colname] , incomparables = FALSE))
  } else {
    print("cette colonne n'existe pas")
  }
}

df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 3, 4), b = 1:4)

val_uniques("a", df)
# [1] 1 3 4
```